# Upon updating my gradle build file to target sdk 28 running nes old game failed

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, updates

I have an old classic game **ice climber** it was working perfect but unfortunately, google update terms to make all apps `targetSdkVersion` at least 26.

so I've updated it and made changes to the gradle/java files but game no more run.

can anyont tell me why it fails or help me fixing that?

my old **gradle** is

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXX.XXX.XXX"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 9
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

and after the update the gradle only it fails the new **gradle**

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XX.XXX.XXX"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

the reason why I added this line `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` as in new version, there is no support for some classes

I get this error log

```
 Build fingerprint: 'HUAWEI/KII-L21/HWKII-Q:6.0.1/HUAWEIKII-L21/C185B321:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '0'
    ABI: 'arm'
    pid: 25304, tid: 25304, name: es.ice:emulator  >>> com.xnes.ice:emulator <<<
    signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
09-08 16:25:52.409 396-396/? A/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 abfc8190  r2 ac229dc0  r3 f36d900c
        r4 ab2ac2f0  r5 ffa398b4  r6 abfc8190  r7 ffa398b0
        r8 ac229dc0  r9 ffffffff  sl ffa398c0  fp ab2abce0
        ip 00000000  sp ffa39868  lr f36d4eef  pc f36d4e3e  cpsr 000f0030
09-08 16:25:52.419 396-396/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
09-08 16:25:52.429 396-396/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00001e3e  /data/app/com.xnes.ice-1/lib/arm/libemu.so
```

Comment: You'll need to give more details about the error for someone to help you. Exactly what happens? Are there any crash messages in the logcat? Where in the code does it fail to run. Your question doesn't give enough information for anyone to help you.

Comment: Please include error or log messages

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no error message/exception it just forward to other screen and is expected to start the game I don't know why that happens but it is too annoying.

can u please tell me what type of details you need to help me solve it?

Comment: I've updated question with some log errors